# updating table using csv file from query in pgsql

Tags: mysql, node.js, postgresql, csv

The concept is on uploading a csv file the old table should be deleted and the new file should replace the old data
I'm using nodejs in it I have written two queries

```
TRUNCATE TABLE test
```

then the second query for updating the table is

```
UPDATE test SET 
 t1 = replace(t1,"")
,t2 = replace(t2,"")
,t3 = replace(t3,"")
,t4 = replace(t4,"")
```

My dummy csv file also have same 4 columns t1,t2,t3,t4 of datatype var char

while executing Im getting the error

```
error: zero-length delimited identifier at or near """"
```

please correct me if the query is wrong

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. after you truncate table you don't have rows to update - you need insert instead.
2. double quotes are used for identifiers - databse objects, so in replace function you use `'string'` and `"column_name"`

Answer (score 1):

This appears to be a postgres issue with your syntax. Change your "" to '' in your replace's. Double quotes identify delimited values, which an empty string can't be representative of, while single quotes just mark a string value. If you require a delimited value here you'll have to add something within the double quotes to make it not an empty string.

As Vao Tsun has pointed out, you will likely need to change your `UPDATE` to an `INSERT`. `UPDATE` modifies current rows, while `INSERT` adds new rows. Since `TRUNCATE TABLE` removes all of your rows, you will none to update in the following query. This won't throw an error since this is valid, but you will likely see no effect from the query.